# Is there a way to check if widget exists before triyng to register it?

Tags: php, wordpress

If you have a widget that is initiated by:

```
function someWidgetLoader () { 
    register_widget( 'someWidget' ); 
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'someWidgetLoader ' );
```

Is there a way to do a check to see if someWidget is already registered with the register_widget() function? Because if it already is, it sends a fatal error saying that the "Cannot redeclare class"

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your widget a name/slug that will not match anything else.

Also if it did exist, you would get a class exists error or some internal WP error.
So wrap your widget class

```
if( ! class_exists('someWidget')
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same error.
After a bit of troubleshooting I discovered that on the theme files where a widget class is added, the class was wrongly defined. An example below for adding Comments widget.

```
<?php
class Comments extends WP_Widget {

   function Comments() {
       $widget_ops = array('description' => 'This is Comments widget.' );
       parent::WP_Widget(false, __('SampleTheme - Comments', 'sampletheme'),$widget_ops);      
   }
}
```

As seen above, the constructor was defined using PHP 4 style. instead of PHP 8. Then the parent was called using PHP 4 style constructor.

So I just fixed it by fixing the constructor and parent call as below:

```
<?php
class Comments extends WP_Widget {

   function __construct() {
       $widget_ops = array('description' => 'This is Comments widget.' );
       parent::__construct(false, __('Sample Theme - Comments', 'sampletheme'),$widget_ops);
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question the OP was asking. The accepted answer is what OP needs.